# Change Timezone in Tomcat

Tags: linux, tomcat, solr, timezone, centos

How can I change the timezone in Tomcat? The timezone used by one of the webapps (Solr) is not right *(compared to MySQL timestamps)*, and I think changing Tomcat's timezone will help. Thanks!

Comment: What user is solr running as, and what is its environment set to?

Comment: I loaded solr as a tomcat webapp, and tomcat6 is running as user `tomcat`. Tomcat6 is running in CentOS 6.3 on port 8080.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Unless tomcat has a personal TZ environment variable, then it uses `/etc/localtime` which on my system is a copy of `/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York`.

Tomcat's personal timezone would be specified in its startup script in a form like:

```
-Duser.timezone=GMT
```

Comment: The tomcat webapp Solr has its time faster than the time in MySQL/PHP by 4 hours. If tomcat uses `/etc/localtime` shouldn't the time be the same for Solr and MySQL?

Comment: I had the same issue. It turns out for me Java was looking in the `/etc/sysconfig/clock` file. This this for comment for [more info](http://grokbase.com/t/tomcat/users/051m0s38p2/how-to-change-the-timezone-for-tomcat#20050120zlgufj6cgdsma7i2olrgcpwia4)

Comment: Then that's an error on Java's part.  /etc/sysconfig/clock is being phased out in recent distros.  Everything should be using /etc/localtime unless the user overrides it.

Answer (score 9):

Here is what I add at beginning of `catalina.sh` (after shabang) to change tomcat's timezone:

```
TOMCAT_TIMEZONE="-Duser.timezone=Europe/Budapest"
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS $TOMCAT_TIMEZONE"
```

And don't forget to restart tomcat to take effect.

Comment: This is not necessarily needed in the catalina.sh, when adding it as a system variable this solution will work as well. :thumbsup:

Comment: That works! I have no idea why, but adding the timezone directly to `CATALINA_OPTS` does not work, but that works! Is `TOMCAT_TIMEZONE` loaded somewhere else?

Comment: @vitormm Nowadays I use timestamp as long, thus timezone doesn't matter much any more in most case. But if you are using spring-boot & embedded tomcat, you may have a try of this: https://javadeveloperzone.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-application-set-default-timezone/

Answer (score 1):

As said Eric Wang you may use

```
TOMCAT_TIMEZONE="-Duser.timezone=Europe/Budapest"
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS $TOMCAT_TIMEZONE"
```

but on CentOS server I didn't find catalina.sh, instead of that I added these variables to /etc/sysconfig/tomcat6, and that's works!

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the timezone of the data being stored in Solr... All date/time values  in Solr are stored via the [DateField](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-4_0_0-BETA/org/apache/solr/schema/DateField.html), which uses UTC.

Comment: The time `last_index_time` in `DataImporHandler`'s `dataimport.properties` is 4 hours ahead of the time used by PHP/MySQL (EDT, America/Newyork). How should I adjust the UTC timezone used by Solr (or Tomcat)

Comment: Check any tomcat startup script or config file for CATALINA_OPTS

Comment: As @stark answered, pass the -Duser.timezone value when starting Tomcat see this... http://www.zeentan.com/wp/apache-solr-timezone-issue

Comment: Most posts say `CATALINA_OPTS` is in `catalina.sh`, but no such file exist at `/usr/share/tomcat6/bin`. Where else should I define the timezone? http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/change_tomcat_s_timezone