# Simulate different timezone between browser and server for local test

Tags: javascript, testing, browser, timezone

I developed a web application (with java) and in it I have a business rule which requires saving the user time signature. But I need to save 3 times: Local timezone user, global timezone, and server timezone.

My problem is to test the local timezone of the user. Anyone know how I can **simulate** *(only for a test in local machine)* a different timezone to the browser, or server, for me to simulate this test?

Note: I thought I'd create a virtual machine and host my application on it, and take the test, it would have only to change the timezone of the virtual machine. So this process will require a long time, I want to know if there is any simple way.

Comment: Well, isn't as simple as changing clock time in Windows? It would simulate Client's time and timezone...

Comment: You need to restart your browser after you change your system's timezone.

Comment: Relevant? http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/8838/faking-system-time-date-with-selenium-webdriver

Comment: @mlewandowski if I change clock time in Windows, change local server too. My execution environment is local, for test

Comment: @EricoSuoza How about changing local Tomcat timezone? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28777322/how-to-change-tomcat-7s-server-timezone

Comment: @BenjaGarrido - Only in some browsers.  Many will pick up on the time zone change automatically.

Comment: for example chrome... this webrowser does not change automatically timezone... I think @MattJohnson

Comment: Actually, it does.  Try it. :) It didn't used to, but they fixed that a while back.  I can't recall which version.  But yes - in general, there will be some that have to be restarted.

Comment: Guys, remember, I need the browser to be different from the server timezone. So I can not restart the browser, right?

Comment: because I need to make sure that the database I will save the local time of the User, and also the local time server.

Comment: @EricoSouza - Honestly, if you're doing it correctly, your server-side code should be completely unaffected by the time zone of the server.  Relying on a server's local time zone setting is an anti-pattern.  Only ever ask for UTC time from the server's clock, and do all time zone conversions yourself in application code.  See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-time-zone-best-practices

Comment: @MattJohnson In my application I need to save in the database, 3 times, just when the user signs a test. These times are: 1 - local time client. 2 - Time of the server location. 3 - Global Time GMT. 
And I need to simulate and test it in my application in my logal machine.

Comment: Right, I read that in your question.  What I'm saying is that #2 *should* be irrelevant in the vast majority of scenarios.  You may be [trying to solve problem X when really you should be looking at problem Y](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Looks like this was asked before, but only answered from a Linux perspective.  I added a Windows answer to that question which may interest you.  See the duplicate link.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered that I can manually set the GMT by tomcat arguments.
To easy:

```
-Duser.timezone=GMT+13
```

As I needed to simulate a zone far away time, I put GMT + 13. Then my server got GMT + 13, and my client (browser) with GMT-3

Comment: @MattJohnson, see my answer. Do you agree?

Comment: I usually discourage using fixed time zone offsets.  The world is much more complex than that.  Be sure to read [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Comment: I also think that while this may accomplish your goal for Java/Tomcat - it doesn't solve the problem you asked about (changing the time zone of the *browser*).  And as I alluded to in the original question comments, if your code behaves any differently whatsoever when you pass in this argument, then you're using the time APIs incorrectly in your code.  Don't ask the server for it's local time - that should be irrelevant.

Comment: @MattJohnson I understood, your explanation is great. This my answer is only for a local test. When my application is in production server, and my client is signing a test and that customer is in Mozambique (timezone UTC + 2), and my server in Brazil (UTC-3), it is necessary I save both times the client signed the test. I don't set -Duser.timezone=GMT in server in production

Answer (score 2):

change your computer's time zone to user's time zone and restart your browser.

Comment: I execute my application in my local environment, so the server timezone = client timezone... but, if I change time in clock window and don't restart my browser, the times will be different, correct?

Comment: are you running your server in your local machine? if yes which server are you using?

Comment: Yes, and I use apache tomcat

Comment: restart your server if you want the server to use computer's time zone