# Jenkins server. new Date. Wrong time

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I using Jenkins server version 2.204.2. Jenkins running in  in Apache Tomcat

I run following code :

```
pipeline {

    agent { node { label 'master' } }

    options {
        timestamps()
    }

    stages {

        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                script {
                    String stamp = new Date().format("YYYY.MM.dd HH:mm:ss")
                    println("Stamp 1 : ${stamp}")

                    String stamp2 = new Date().format("YYYY.MM.dd HH:mm:ss", TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Jerusalem"))
                    println("Stamp 2 : ${stamp2}")
}}}}}
```

Output (local time is 18:30 now. My timezone is Asia/Jerusalem) is:

> 18:30:02  Stamp 1 : 2020.06.14 **15:30:02**
>
> 18:30:02  Stamp 2 : 2020.06.14 18:30:02

In systeminfo page (http:///jenkins/systemInfo) I see user.timezone=Asia/Jerusalem

Why by default new Date() returns wrong time ? 
Same code works properly on another server

Thank you

Update: this code runs on master.

Answer (score 0):

You might also have to set `org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.fmt.timeZone=America/New_York`.

Answer (score 0):

You could check to see your [timezone is.set correctly in Jenkins](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/change-time-zone/).

But you should also check what [timezone Tomvat is configured for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28779635/598141).

There's also the matter of what TZ your OS is set for.. 
This serverfault answer detais some [OS level TZ issues](https://serverfault.com/q/406181/189417)

Our master is in one TZ, but our nodes are on servers in 3 different TZ and our users are all over. .We prefer to set everything in UTC.