# Java + Postgres: time shift between app and database

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, date, timestamp

One of field of my table has following format:

```
trackdate TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
```

POJO:

```
private Timestamp trackDate;
```

where Timestamp is java.sql.Timestamp.

The problem is that when I have a date, for instance, 2017-05-08 22:16:15.551 in Europe/Kiev time zone, the database adds 3 hours (Europe/Kiev itself) and I have 2017-05-09 01:16:27.551+03 there.

hibernate mapping is pretty simple:

```
    <property name="trackDate" type="timestamp">
        <column name="TRACKDATE" not-null="true"/>
    </property>
```

No any additional conversions between app and database are. The Tomcat starts with:

```
export TOMCAT_TIMEZONE="-Duser.timezone=Europe/Kiev"
```

Database' time zone is also set to:

```
timezone = 'Europe/Kiev'
```

What is the problem? Why I see additional three hours?

Comment: looks like your client uses utc, not kiev time

Comment: `TOMCAT_TIMEZONE` will not change the time zone for Tomcat. You need to put that into CATALINA_OPTS or into `setenv.sh`. See e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28777322/how-to-change-tomcat-7s-server-timezone or here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12112188/330315

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your database thinks stores your time as UTC and converts it to Kiev-Time. Some litterature on hibernate and timestamps: http://in.relation.to/2016/09/12/jdbc-time-zone-configuration-property/ Look at workarounds at the bottom of the page...

Comment: That's correct. A Postgres `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` is always normalized to UTC [as documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#AEN6247)

Answer (score 0):

**Your code and database are working correctly.** The time in the database is listing the time in one of the standard Postgre time stamp forms [documented here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-datetime.html#AEN5865) (see section 8.5.1.3, "Time Stamps", also [this table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-TIME-TABLE) might help clear things up as well).

**In other words**, `2017-05-09 01:16:27.551+03` has the same meaning of `2017-05-08 22:16:15.551 Europe/Kiev`, with `+03` in `2017-05-09 01:16:27.551+03` indicating the 3-hour offset that the "Europe/Kiev" timezone has from UTC.