# tomcat showing incorrect time

Tags: java, tomcat, war

I Have a set of war files installed which is executed from tomcat.

The problem is that tomcat is not picking up the right time ..

As indicated in the log files

```
    Apr 18, 2018 12:02:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.76
Apr 18, 2018 12:02:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Oct 30 2017 10:21:55 UTC
    Apr 18, 2018 12:02:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.76.0
    Apr 18, 2018 12:02:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Linux
    Apr 18, 2018 12:02:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
```

the time shown above is Apr 18, 2018 12:02:14 AM however the current time as in the system is as below.

Tue Apr 17 20:15:33 IST 2018

I Have checked the answer of below hower [Change Timezone in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112188/change-timezone-in-tomcat) it seems that is not producing the desired result

I dont have catalina.sh in my system and the output of

/etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Kolkata

i.e all is in IST

```
# timedatectl
      Local time: Tue 2018-04-17 20:21:29 IST
  Universal time: Tue 2018-04-17 14:51:29 UTC
        RTC time: Tue 2018-04-17 14:51:29
       Time zone: Asia/Kolkata (IST, +0530)
     NTP enabled: no
NTP synchronized: no
 RTC in local TZ: no
      DST active: n/a
```

I have even restarted tomcat and even the server but to no help

Comment: Why do you mean by *you don't have catalina.sh*? Do you not have access to it? It should be in {tomcat_home}/bin

Comment: i have checked in tomcat/home the file catalina.sh doesn't exists. We are using centos 7.

Comment: The file is supposed to be in the `bin` subdirectory of Tomcat server's installation, not tomcat user's directory. What command do you use to run the server?

Comment: find the contents of /usr/share/tomcat/bin -rw-r--r-- 1 root tomcat 29207 Oct 30 15:52 bootstrap.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root tomcat  1647 Oct 30 15:52 catalina-tasks.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   38548 Oct 30 15:52 tomcat-juli.jar

Comment: Also I run the tomcat server using systemctl . systemctl start tomcat

Comment: When using `systemd` to launch Tomcat, you'll have to check to see where configuration values are read. Those scripts may be skipping your `bin/startup.sh` file (which is where this kind of configuration ought to go, not in `bin/catalina.sh`).

Answer (score 1):

I assume your running your application on linux.
Type date in your terminal on remote server and also check the date time on your local system and find the difference in time between them ( ie Timezone offset ) and upadate the timezone related sample code given below

```
$ date
```

Psuedo java code to handle date assuming UTC to IST conversion

```
public static String UTCtoIST(String dateUTC, DateFormat inputdf, DateFormat expecteddf) {
    try {
        inputdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        Date _dateUTC = inputdf.parse(dateUTC);
        expecteddf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
        return expecteddf.format(_dateUTC);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //handle exception here
    }
    return null;
}
```

Example for calling method

```
 DateFormat inputdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
 DateFormat expecteddf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
 UTCtoIST(toDateInUTC, inputdf, expecteddf);
```

Comment: As the date difference lies in Apache Tomcat. The Developers will not agree to do a code change. I was seeking a way to make changes in tomcat.